# I have to click on a MessageBox Button several times to come out of the Message Box

Tags: c#, winforms

Quit Button Click Event.

```
`void buttn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //QUIT BUTTON CLICK EVENT. 
    {
       if (MessageBox.Show("LEAVE CURRENT GAME?", "QUIT CONFIRMATION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(buttn); .. PLAY AGAIN BUTTON.
            this.Controls.Remove(buttn2);
            for (int i = 0; i <= gencount; i++)
            {
               this.Controls.Remove(panel[i]);
               this.Controls.Remove(label200[i]);
               this.Controls.Remove(label100[i]);
               this.Controls.Remove(Tbox[i]);
            }
               this.Controls.Remove(AttemptsRem);
               this.Controls.Remove(AttemptNum);
               this.Controls.Remove(TimeRem);
               this.Controls.Remove(Min);
               this.Controls.Remove(Sec);
               this.Controls.Remove(misc);
               this.ReftoForm2.Show(); To go back to the starting form 
        }
        else
            buttn.Focus();
    }
```

Form1 activate Event.

```
 private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ui_formCowsAndBulls.rdbSinglePlayer.Checked == true)//Static variable
        {

            //GetAllTheWords(); .. Am still working on getting a the 4 letter words
            //GetDistinctElements(); .. randomly out of a list.
            textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
            textBox1.Focus();
            foreach (string val in distinctWords)
            {
                if (val == "ABLE") .. For single player,the guess word is ABLE.
                    textBox1.Text = val;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
        //textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

PLAY AGAIN CLICK EVENT

```
 private void buttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //PLAY AGAIN CLICK EVENT.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= gencount; i++)
          {
            this.Controls.Remove(panel[i]);
            this.Controls.Remove(label200[i]);
            this.Controls.Remove(label100[i]);
            this.Controls.Remove(Tbox[i]);
          }

            this.Controls.Remove(AttemptsRem);
            this.Controls.Remove(AttemptNum);
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Focus();
            incrpanel = 0; gencount = 0; count = 10;
            this.Controls.Remove(TimeRem);
            this.Controls.Remove(Min);
            this.Controls.Remove(Sec);
            this.Controls.Remove(misc);
            this.textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
            this.Controls.Remove(buttn);
            this.Controls.Remove(buttn2);
    }
```

My question is I dont come out of the message boxes when I click message box button NO.I come out of the message box the first time I play the game,But If i play the game a second time,it takes me two clicks to come out of the Message box.If I play the game a third time,it takes me 3 clicks on either the Yes or NO button to come out of the Message Box.I hope you folks can help me.I had posted the same question before but without the code.Hope the code helps.

Comment: There seems too be no problem there. What are you doing in the "play again" button handler?

Comment: @Guffa I have added the Play again click event,Not much happening there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be subscribing to the `Click`-event:

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(buttn2_Click);
```

in a place in the code where it's called more than once, so when the button is clicked the MessageBox will be shown, and when the `buttn2_Click` event handler (-your code that you posted) is finished - it will run again, showing another MessageBox, for as many times as the subscription (the "...+=..." above) was done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I am going check that.Yes I have written the Event handler in many places,but Its always taken care of by an if-else block so that it runs only once.Anyways I am going to go through my code again.

Comment: @user1789527 I don't know if I made myself clear. You should have it only _once_ in the whole running of the application, unless you are creating a _new_ Form which contains the buttn2 Button - in which case you will need it only once in the life of that Form. The point is: When the `buttn2_Click` event handler (-your code) is run - the subscription is NOT exhausted. So if you subscribe to it again - you will have TWO subscriptions. So any time someone will click the button - the handler will run twice.

Comment: @user1789527 In your comment - I assume you meant "event subscription" not "Event handler". The handler is the code in your question. The subscription is the line of code I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I have taken care of the event subscription in such a way that it happens only once,even though the i have written the line of code in your answer in many places is what I meant to say.I will recheck everything just to be on the safer side.Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @user1789527 You're welcome. (And don’t forget to check the designer _code_. You might have double-clicked the button on the designer and got a subscription there automatically.) Good luck.

Comment: I am generating the Buttons dynamically,so There is very little chance of double clicking on the designer :),right?

Comment: I see that you have: `this.Controls.Remove(buttn2);`. So you probably have `this.Controls.Add(buttn2);` somewhere as well. Perhaps you have an event subscription after that.

Comment: Well,I most certainly do .. But I have taken care of it in an if-else block,so that the event subscription happens only once.But I am beginning to doubt myself,because its clear from your explanation that the event subscriiption has happened somewhere twice or more.

Comment: @user1789527 I wasn't clear. If you have it on the _first_ time the button is added to the form - that's fine, of course. But if you have it again when you **re**-put the button on the Form - you shouldn't. Removing the button from the Form does **not** cancel its event subscriptions (as far as I know).

Comment: There are 3 cases in which I am adding the buttons,one when the player guesses the word.Two when the time for guessing the word is exceeded.three when the player is unable to guess the word in the given chances.All 3 conditions are mutually exclusive.So at any point of time the Button and the subscription are added are only once.

Comment: wait,I rthink I got what you are trying to tell me,How does remove a subscription.Is it (-=)?

Comment: Yes. ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​But you don't need that. Just have the subscription _once_ when you create the Form (assuming you're only creating the Form once) and that's that.

Comment: I am not removing the subscription.I think there in lies the problem.Is that what you have been trying to tell me all this while.

Comment: Wow,Thank you very Much Ispiro.Sorry if i took some time in understanding what you were telling me.

Comment: More or less. _Don't_ remove it. Just don't re-subscribe to it.